# „Danke für Ihre Bemühungen/Mühe“ in Brief oder E-Mail

Tags: word-choice, formality, letter

*Die Frage zielt* nicht *auf formelle Brief-Gestaltung ab, sondern auf die Frage, ob ein Dank für „Bemühungen“ oder „Mühe“ das Falsche ausdrückt oder die richtige Konnotation transportiert.*

---

Während „sehr geehrt“ und MfG im Briefverkehr dank Konvention feststehen, hadere ich oft mit der Zeile vor der Schlussformel, und zwar beim Dank für die (mutmaßliche/erhoffte/suggerierte) Bestrebung des Gegenübers, mein Anliegen zu bearbeiten:

> Vielen Dank für Ihre Mühe.
>
> Danke für Ihre Bemühungen.

Ich will damit ausdrücken, dass ich es (wert-)schätze, dass der andere meine Anfrage bearbeitet, sei es auch nur mit einer Absage. Ich möchte mich vorab bedanken, dass sich der andere für mein Schreiben Zeit nimmt, unabhängig von der Antwort. Danke eben, dass ich Mühe machen darf.

Für „Mühe“ scheint es leider kein Synonym zu geben. Ein Danke für die *Arbeit*, die *Bestrebung*, die *Bearbeitung* oder gar die *Zeit* klingt auch nicht sooo passend.

Außerdem denkt man rasch an „zu bemüht“ oder den Klassiker „er bemühte sich redlich“. Beides ist natürlich nicht gemeint, sondern die Arbeitsbelastung und der Zeitaufwand, den ich dem Gegenüber durch mein Schreiben beschert habe.

Eine *Entschuldigung* für die Mühe wäre allerdings eindeutig zu devot…

**Ist „Bemühungen“ vlt. doch der richtige Anlass zum Danken?**

**Gibt es ein positiveres Wort für „Mühe“, das die dahinterstehende Arbeit einschließt?**

Comment: Für mich hört sich "Danke für Ihre Bemühungen" danach an, als hätte jemand versucht zu helfen, aber am Ende ist nichts dabei herausgekommen. Also quasi als Ende eines Schriftverkehrs.

"Vielen Dank für Ihre Mühe" trifft es für mich schon eher, aber ich empfinde auch die negative Konnotation davon.

Ich würde am Ehesten Schreiben "Vielen Dank im Voraus".

Allerdings ist das alles nur meine persönliche Meinung, habe keinerlei Quellen dafür.

Comment: @RoyPJ: Persönliches (Sprach-)Gefühl hilft schon sehr, wenn es keine Konvention gibt. Danke auch für die Unterscheidung zwischen *Bemühung* (am Ende) und *Mühe* (im Vorgang). „Danke im voraus“ ist zwar gut und neutral, irgendwie fehlt aber das *wofür*.

Comment: "Hilfe" statt "Mühe" ist positiver. Passt nicht immer, aber oft.

Comment: @Gerhard Absolut. Menschen erinnern sich nicht gern daran, daß etwas anstrengend war, aber sie *lieben* den Gedanken, daß sie jemandem wertvolle Hilfe geleistet haben.

Comment: Hilfe ist schön, ist aber für Bewerbungen zu devot. IMHO.

Comment: @Thomas Wer redet denn von einer Bewerbung?

Comment: *Bemühungen* geht gar nicht - Das hört sich zu sehr nach "hat sich sehr bemüht..." an. "Hilfe" finde ich gut, und "Danke für Ihre Mühe" geht auch prima.

Comment: @KilianFoth: Spätestens, wenn das Anstrengende erfolgreich bewältigt wurde, kann man sich durchaus gerne daran erinnern. Gerade im Zusammenhang mit einem Dank kann das schon passen, da "Mühe" klar zum Ausdruck bringt, dass sich der Dankende des Umstands bewusst ist, den er dem Angesprochenen aufbürdet. Zudem schwingt bei "Mühe" mE eine geringere Erwartungshaltung mit als bei "Hilfe" (welcher Unmensch weist schon ein nachvollziehbares Hilfegesuch ab?).

Answer (score 10):

Ich persönlich finde es sehr schwer hier pauschalisierend einen Rat zu geben, das hängt immer vom Kontext ab. Bedankung ist immer gut; "Mühe" bevorzugt, "Bemühungen" haben immer etwas gezwungenes, unvollendetes. "Zeit" ist auch gut und ist m.E. schön passiv.

Vorschlag 1:

> Vielen Dank für Ihre Aufmerksamkeit/Zeit.

Vorschlag 2:

> Über eine Rückmeldung, auch negativer Art, würde ich mich freuen (und wäre Ihnen mit Dank verbunden).

Comment: ＋１ für *Zeit* (wobei diese nicht die Be*arbeit*ung einschließt und auch etwas zu devot klingen könnte). Natürlich gibt es keine *ein*deutige Antwort (daher die Frage), aber Vorschläge, Alternativen und Bedenken hinsichtlich der Konnotation sind hilfreich genug.

Answer (score 3):

Du könntest auch mit einem

> Vielen Dank

schließen, ohne zu spezifizieren, wofür genau oder mit

> Vielen Dank für Ihre Hilfe

was wiederum unterstellt, dass es zu einer gewissen Form von Erfolg führt. Statt *Mühe* wäre auch das ökonomischer klingende *Aufwand* eine Alternative oder danke für das *Engagement*. Es wird sehr vom Einzelfall abhängen, was angemessen ankommt und was eher nicht.

Answer (score 2):

Immer dann, wenn ich zuvor geschildert habe, was ich von jemandem möchte, benutze ich die Schlussformel: *Mit bestem Dank und freundlichen Grüßen.* Ich halte es für strategisch günstiger, die/den andere*n gar nicht erst darauf aufmerksam zu machen, dass sie/er sich Mühe geben soll / muss / darf ...

Answer (score 0):

Danke für Ihr Mühewalten!

Finde ich sehr schön. Etwas veraltet, aber ich mag sowas.

Comment: Ich würde es eher als "ziemlich veraltet" betrachten und nicht verwenden. Vielleicht kein guter Tip für Leute, die deutsch lernen.

Comment: Das würde ich als "gestelzt" bewerten, daher hier -1.

Answer (score 0):

Bemühungen finde ich auch sehr unpassend.

Ich schreibe daher immer nur am Ende:

> Vielen Dank und einen schönen Tag!